# Remove sub IEnumerable from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a `IEnumerable<Byte>` from which I want to remove a sequence of bytes that could appear only once. The first array can be quite big but the second one cannot exceed 50bytes

What is the best way (and fastest way) to do that ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you trying to remove *a specific subsequence exactly as-is*, or *all elements of the subsequence* regardless of how they're ordered or grouped together?  The latter is trivial; the former I don't think can be done with LINQ.

Comment: @MasonWheeler : Unfortunatly, I have to remove the first occurrence of this exact sub-sequence (same order) in the `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create static method for that, something like this:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<byte> RemoveSubSequence(this IEnumerable<Byte> sequence, IEnumerable<Byte> subSequence)
    {
        List<byte> list = sequence.ToList();
        byte[] subSequenceList = subSequence.ToArray();

        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (; i < list.Count && count != subSequenceList.Length; i++)
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < subSequenceList.Length && count != subSequenceList.Length; i2++)
                if (list[i + i2] == subSequenceList[i2]) count++; else count = 0;

        list.RemoveRange(i - 1, count);

        return list;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
        IEnumerable<byte> bytes = new byte[] { 5, 7, 6, 9, 1, 5, 7, 6, 7, 0, 6, 4, 0, 6, 4, 8 };
        IEnumerable<byte> subSequence = new byte[] { 6, 7, 0, 6, 4, 0, 6, 4, 8 };

        bytes = bytes.RemoveSubSequence(subSequence);

        foreach (var item in bytes) Console.Write(item + "  ");

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
```

Output : `5, 7, 6, 9, 1, 5, 7,`

Comment: Did you try `bytes = 5, 5, 7, 6` and `subSequence=5, 7`?

Comment: Yeah it looks like there's still a few bugs in this.

Comment: OK, now `bytes = 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 8` and `subSequence = 5, 7, 5, 8`.

Comment: `bytes = 5`, `subSequence = 5, 7`? Also, for a more efficient implementation Google "Knuth Morris Pratt".

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable are readonly, if you want to delete some inhabitants of it, you should call it as a list instead "select ... bla.ToList()"

Comment: I think what the OP really means is filtering the `IEnumerable` as they iterate it.

Comment: That cannot be the answer

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. I managed to do it by a same way as using ToList()

Comment: @kyle : Why ? The answer cannot be "it's not possible" ?